# How do I Sweave a multiple-file project?

Tags: r, latex, sweave, literate-programming

I am writing my thesis in LaTeX and because things got a bit long for my taste, I had split it into several files. Let's call them `thesis.tex`, `intro.tex`, `mat_n_met.tex`, `rslts.tex` and `discsn.tex`. I have linked `intro.tex`, `mat_n_met.tex`, `rslts.tex` and `discsn.tex` through `thesis.tex` with `\include{intro}` (and so on...).
I have also created a separate file called `r_crunching.Rnw` (that I run through Sweave) that holds a chunk that runs the R script with data analysis and chunks that produce pdf outputs of graphs that I embed via `\includegraphics` (in e.g., `rslts.tex`). Still following?

If I run a Rnw (i.e. I renamed `rslts.tex` to `rslts.Rnw`) without "a link" to the chunk with the R script, you will get a `Sweave()` error saying the reference in `\Sexpr{}` doesn't exist. Is there a way, without merging all the files into a single .Rnw, to call `\Sexpr{}` in say `rslts.Rnw`?

Other methods how to accomplish this are welcome.

Comment: off-topic, but on the off-chance this is helpful: http://staff.acecrc.org.au/~mdsumner/TCallaghan/ That template shows how to use the include/includeonly infrastructure, and has all the pieces at least for one institution. I used it directly, and have just replaced chap1.tex etc. with my Rnw equivalents and added Sweave to the pre-latex process.

Comment: I edited the title to say how I understood your question. Feel free to edit again, if I understood it wrong. (I still didn't really understand the problem and how the accepted answer helped, though.)

Comment: The problem was that at least two of the files were Sweave files and that the results from one weren't able to be seen by the other.  I think the original title was simpler and clearer, though informal.  Roman's still active here, so maybe he'll jump in, but in the meantime I'll put it back closer to how it started.  Paŭlo, I hope this isn't rude, but why edit a question you don't understand?

Comment: @Aaron, no offense taken. I think "help me" is in general a bad type of title, and [I'm now going through all questions of some tags with some of these bad key words](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101923/ive-found-a-particular-set-of-questions-with-bad-titles-how-should-i-proceed/102197#102197) trying to give them better titles. (My tag here was [tag:latex], not [tag:r] or [tag:sweave]). You are right, I should have simply commented in this case.

Comment: Paŭlo, thanks for not taking offense and providing a great answer to my question.  Your work to improve the site is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget for a second that you are dealing with Sweave and just think of the latex problem -- for which `\include` and `\includeonly` offer solutions.  Try that with a few simple test files.

Once you have that figured out, fold Sweave back into the mix and it just work as Sweave is after 'merely' a pre-processing step, albeit a very clever one.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using RStudio (http://www.rstudio.com/ide/). Sweave is nicely integrated into that IDE and it supports multi-file documents. Even Synctex and TeX error log navigation still work when working with multi-file documents.

From the master file you can include child files using

```
\SweaveInput{Child.Rnw}
```

You can link a child file back to the master file by including the directive

```
% !Rnw root = Master.Rnw
```

in the child file. That way when working on a child file and typesetting it, RStudio know to typeset the master file.

The details are explained in the RStudio documentation at http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/multiple_rnw_files

Answer (score 2):

To expand Dirk's and mjm's answer, I would suggest using `\include`'s and Makefiles.

Suppose you have a master file: `master.tex`. In that file, you include some `.tex` and `.Rnw` files, i.e.

```
\include chapter1
\include chapter2
\include chapter3
....
```

Now the following Makefile provides functions for creating the `.tex`, `.R` and `.pdf` files:

```
.SUFFIXES: .tex .pdf .Rnw .R

MAIN = master
##List your your .Rnw includes
RNWINCLUDES = chapter1 chapter2 chapter3
TEX = $(RNWINCLUDES:=.tex)
RFILES = $(RNWINCLUDES:=.R)
RNWFILES = $(INCLUDES:=.Rnw)

all: $(MAIN).pdf
    $(MAIN).pdf: $(TEX) $(MAIN).tex

R: $(RFILES)

.Rnw.R:
     R CMD Stangle $<

.Rnw.tex:
     R CMD Sweave $<

.tex.pdf:
     pdflatex $<
     bibtex $*
     pdflatex $<
     pdflatex $<
```

Essentially, the `.SUFFIXES` provide a set of rules for convert from one file format to another. For example, to convert from `.Rnw` to `.R`, we use the command

```
`R CMD Stangle $<`
```

Answer (score 1):

one fairly obvious answer is to use a makefile, possibly using package cachesweave, to process the relevant files in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to multi-file projects in Sweave (under Rstudio) is the following:

1) Create a master file, say `master.Rnw`, in which you have the calls to the subfiles `intro.Rnw`, `matmet.Rnw`, etc:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
% \usepackage{blah, blah} as you wish

\graphicspath{ {./figs/}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\include{intro} % a call to 'intro.Rnw'
\include{matmet} % a call to 'matmet.Rnw'
\include{results} % a call to 'results.Rnw'
\include{discuss} % a call to 'discuss.Rnw'

\end{document}
```

2) Create the subfiles. I'm giving here only the first one, `intro.Rnw`. Please note that  in the subfiles you **do not use** preambular commands such as `\documentclass` or `\begin{document}`

```
\chapter{Introduction}\label{ch:intro}
\section{This is section 01}
In section 01 we are concerned about whether \texttt{Sexpr} could possibly work. The chunk below creates a variable \em{a} which will be referred to by this command later on.

<<>>=
a <- 1+2
@

Ok, if it is working, we shall see number 3 right here: \Sexpr{a}.
```

3) After saving modifications in 'intro.Rnw', simply go to 'master.Rnw'  and compile it using Ctrl+Shift+K and... voilá:

[Screenshot of the file created by the above command.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrDJz.png)